# How to create shared assets in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have read [Using Android Assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows). My problem is a bit different because I want to create a folder called `assets` in the "shared project" as follows. Android and iOS projects are removed for the sake of simplicity. Only UWP is left for demonstration purposes.

[image]

I have already created a folder named `assets` and save a file `secret.txt` in it. However, I don't know which `Build Action` value should I attach to this `secret.txt`. The secret file is not a real secret.

Any comments and suggestions are always welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set files as EmbeddedResources and manipulate them as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files?tabs=windows#embedding-in-shared-projects